# Node-Red "http request" node stuck in requesting if no connection

Tags: http, httprequest, node-red

I have a flow with a `http request` node in it, which makes `POST` calls to a web service.

Everything works ok, but if the device where Node-Red is running loses connection to Internet (it is connected through LTE), the node keeps stuck in requesting state, instead of returning an error.

[image: node requesting]

Is this the normal behaviour? Could I solve it by setting a timeout? How could it be done?

Comment: How long did you leave it? The default timeout for http-requests is 2mins

Comment: I have tried by modifying `httpRequestTimeout` property in `settings.js`, but it keeps hanging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating Node-RED to latest version resolved the issue. Now I get an error as I would expect, and Node-RED does not hang.

[image]

I have updated from version v0.19.5 to v 1.0.3.

Answer (score 3):

To set timeout in your request, set msg.httpRequestTimeout with the number of miliseconds at the  node before your request.

**Example:**

[image]

inside node "Set Timeout"

```
msg.httpRequestTimeout = 60000;
return msg;
```

Answer (score 0):

My approach to this would be to first check if the internet is available (example: by pinging google) if it fails, then return an error.

Answer (score 0):

you can set `requestTimeout` input value for this particular node.